# Typing Axios response based on status code

Tags: typescript, axios

I have a backend api that sends back responses in two different scenarios.

When successful, it sends

```
{
  lastConnectedAt: Date; 
}
```

if the request was bad, it sends below object with 404 status code.

```
{
  error: {
    message: string;
  };
}
```

In typescript, how should I type both scenarios?

```
export interface GenericErrorResponse {
  error: {
    message: string;
  };
}

export interface LoginSuccessResponse {
  lastConnectedAt: Date;
}
```

```
import { AxiosInstance } from "axios";
import { authApi } from "../apis/auth/authApi";
import { LoginSuccessResponse } from "../apis/auth/types";

class AuthService {
  constructor(private api: AxiosInstance) {}

  public requestLogin = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    const { data } = await this.api.post<LoginSuccessResponse>("/api/login", { email, password });
    return data;
  };
}

export default new AuthService(authApi);
```

As you see, I typed the successful response. But how on the other side?

Answer (score 1):

`data` will always be of type `LoginSuccessResponse`. A 404 error will make axios throw an error. That can have many reasons, you can narrow it down like this:

```js
function isAxiosError(error: unknown): error is AxiosError {
  return (error as AxiosError).isAxiosError !== undefined
}

...
try {
  const { data } = await this.api.post<LoginSuccessResponse>('/api/login', {
    email,
    password,
  })
  return data
} catch (err) {
  if (isAxiosError(err) && err.response?.status == 404) {
    // handle 404 error
  } else {
    // Handle all other errors
  }
}
...
```

If you want requestLogin to return either data or an error you can "handle" the error by returning it (`return err as GenericErrorResponse`). Return type of your function would then be `Promise<LoginSuccessResponse | GenericErrorResponse>`.